# I'm trying to install Blender 2.78c on my windows 7 but it's frozen on the install screen

Tags: installation

As you can probably already tell from the title I'm trying to install blender on my windows 7 but its completely frozen on the setup wizard 'installing blender' Yes, I have tried downloading it again numerous times and even reboot my computer but still nothing, any help?
[image]

Comment: Cancel that and use the portable, no-install, ZIP provided version.